# Django database data not showing in Templete

Tags: html, django, jinja2

I have a class `HardBook` that inherits from `Book`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Book Title', max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField('Book Cover', upload_to='covers')
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length= 350)
    
class HardBook(Book):
    quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity')
```

views.py

```
class BookCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(BookCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['softbooks'] = SoftBook.objects.all()
        context['hardbooks'] = SoftBook.objects.all()
        return context
```

I want to display the field data in a table, I want to show `title`, `image` and `quantity`. Everthing is displayed except `quantity`.

```
{% for hardbook in hardbooks %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="cover-image" style="background-image:url({{hardbook.image.url}});"></div>
        </td>
        <td>{{hardbook.title}}</td>
        <td>{{hardbook.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please add the view for this page to your question.

Comment: What is hardbooks ? you are using a queryset im assuming? share that too

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat fortunately enough I have found the problem. It was in the `views.py` file. I used the `SoftBook` instead of `HardBook`.